# My car won't start but has dash lights headlights n radio all normal

Tags: starter, no-crank-no-start

I just got a 2008 Ford Freestyle and I noticed every time I started it to go some where it had less n less cranking power, then when I went to start it at the grocery store it cranked s-l-o-w-l-e-y once or twice then nothing. No clicking no cranking, just dead. Tried a jump start, but didn't help. The lights and other electrical seem to function just fine???? Any thoughts?

Comment: By "Jump Start", do you mean that you used cables to connect your battery to another car's battery?   Did you leave the cables connected for a while before you tried to start the car?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a dead or dying battery - jump start or replace battery, but if you jump start it won't start the next time..

And then have the charging system checked just in case.

Edit: so if jumping and it still does not start then it could be the starter or the cable feeding the starter.

One way to check is to put the jump lead directly on the starter and see if it works... But this is now more difficult as vehicles have less and less free space.

Comment: Jump start, but did no good and my dash, head, dome lights n radio all work normally. Could this be a bad starter? I've only had car for a week or so from an auction so I have little to no background on it.

Comment: Just because low current devices like interior lights and the radio seem to work, does not mean the battery is good.  Do the interior lights dim when you try to start the engine? Can you turn the headlights on and see if they look dim?

Comment: You drove it to the grocery then it cranked slowly.  The engine is warm so should crank easier than when cold, even with a weak battery.  I would suspect the charging system first.  It sounds like the alternator is not charging the battery.  Many auto parts stores will test the alternator for free.